# Avocado stem stops after 1- 2 cm

Tags: seedlings, avocado

I have this avocado pit that I have been growing for 2-3 months. It had a big strong root, and then a strong stem came out. After about 1 cm it stopped and died.

Then another, thinner, stem came out, and this one apparently died too. And there is another one after that which still looks pretty good but  maybe I have to do something to keep them alive after 1-2 cm.

I have to mention I have started with the toothpick suspended in water method and then I just added soil gradually. Also, I have 3 other avocado trees that are about 20 cm (8 inches).
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vZRY.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing, tried to grow avocados from seed with sticks in water. Most will work out and grow into plants, but some of them won't grow, just like you describe. It seems like it wants to grow, but stops. I think the problem is the pit, not your method. Maybe a spontaneous mutation in the pit?

Luckily avocados pits are easy to get, so you can try as often as necessary.

Comment: You might be right, i have 2 more that got blocked in the same state. I'll just try different things like changing the water cleaning/cutting part of the root, a bit of experimenting, is something happens i'll post it up.